# How to get rid of singletons in PHP

Tags: php, refactoring, singleton

I recently found out that singletons are bad.
I couldn't find answer how to recreate my current code to be without singleton.

What i have now:

```
class checker {
   private static $inst;
   public static function getInst() {
    if(!isset(self::$inst))
        throw new Exception("Error 13: Check module not started.");
    else
        return self::$inst;
   }

   function __construct()   {

    if(!isset(self::$inst))
        self::$inst = $this;
    else {
        throw new Exception("Error 10: Checker not ready?");
        exit;
    }
   }
}
```

And then i use

```
checker::getInst()->blaBlaFunction();
```

**I need it in multiple classes and only one instance of it.**

Comment: nothing is 'bad' nothing is 'good' its all relative

Comment: The jury is still out on whether singletons are bad or not - while some people consider them the spawn of sata, I believe they still have a place when used for objects that truly are unique, so still have their place as a design pattern. Don't throw tools out of your toolbox just because somebody else with an axe to grind tells you to. Justify them based on circumstance, but don't use them as a universal solution either

Comment: Incidentally, your __construct() should be private or protected rather than defaulting to public, and you should also prevent cloning